# Docker is running. Docker Desktop says "Docker Desktop stopped..."

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-desktop

I've installed Docker and Docker Desktop on my Ubuntu 20.04 VM using this guide:

https://linuxiac.com/how-to-install-docker-desktop-on-ubuntu/

Everything is running, but my Docker Desktop app can't seem to connect to Docker itself.

`service docker status` returns:

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2022-05-13 14:49:12 PDT; 4 days ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
   Main PID: 1086 (dockerd)
      Tasks: 18
     Memory: 73.0M
     CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
             └─1086 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock

Warning: some journal files were not opened due to insufficient permissions.
```

However, this is what I get when I try to configure things in Docker Desktop. When I click on settings, I get a perpetual loading spinner.

[image: docker desktop error]

### What I've tried

1. I've restarted docker with `sudo service docker stop / start`
2. I've clicked restart with the Docker Desktop dropdown menu on the top right of my Ubuntu Desktop.
3. I've added my user to the `docker` group.

What steps can I take to debug this? Is there anything obvious I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same problem on Debian 11 and Docker Desktop 4.8.1

1. If you are using Linux inside a VM, verify virtualization support. Docker Desktop runs a VM that requires KVM support.

https://docs.docker.com/desktop/linux/install/#kvm-virtualization-support

2. If you're using VMWare, you need to enable CPU counters.

https://github.com/canonical/multipass/issues/1085

3. Verify qty with

   `egrep -c '(svm|vmx)' /proc/cpuinfo`
4. You need to stop and disable Docker.

   ```
   $ sudo service docker stop
   $ sudo systemctl disable docker.service
   $ sudo systemctl disable docker.socket
   ```

   Then, restart your linux and your Docker desktop.

   Even more, if you run `docker ps` as root user , you don't use docker desktop. You have another list of containers.
5. Be careful if you change "Setting-> Resources-> Advanced: Disk Image location" , you must not delete the default file 1.8G => `home/YOUR_USER/.docker/desktop/vms/0/data/Docker.raw`

   You can change the path, but you need to keep that file in that location.

[image]

Reset factory
[image]

Docker desktop restart

[image]

Docker service status after reboot my computer

[image]

Full history:

```
sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-compose-plugin
sudo usermod -aG docker YOUR_USER
sudo apt install gnome-terminal
sudo apt install qemu-kvm libvirt-clients libvirt-daemon-system bridge-utils virtinst libvirt-daemon virt-manager -y
sudo usermod -aG kvm YOUR_USER
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install ./docker-desktop-4.8.1-amd64.deb
sudo systemctl disable docker.service
sudo systemctl disable docker.socket
```

Test VirtualBox VM - Ubuntu 20.04

[image]

Comment: Following your instructions. I just rebooted, and since docker is disabled, it's not running. Should I start it up again?
Docker Desktop is giving me "Docker Desktop stopped...", but I think it's because Docker is not running.

Comment: Restarting with the context menu doesn't seem to do anything :/ Docker desktop is just brought into focus. Seems like it should close the window and then open it, but nothing happens.

Comment: then, the last silver bullet... Reset to factory defaults button. ( whith docker stopped and disabled ) - image added

Comment: Unfortunately, no dice. Thanks for taking the time with the answer

Comment: And yes, this is Ubuntu inside a VM.

Comment: ahhhh ok, you must to allow virtualize your proc inside your VM.  That is the reason. Verify https://docs.docker.com/desktop/linux/install/#kvm-virtualization-support

Comment: Ah, thank you. I’ll update you when I get KVM enabled on this VM. It’s run by another team

Comment: I've gone ahead and enabled nested virtualization, and enabled KVM with modprobe kvm_intel, and followed the other steps in the documentation. I'm still getting the same behavior. Just checking if you have any other ideas for troubleshooting steps

Comment: I also ran sudo apt install qemu-kvm libvirt-daemon-system libvirt-clients bridge-utils

Comment: Here's my log:
https://gist.github.com/cyruscuenca/197335938aba3e24b14f458602516075

Should I be running the docker service before I start docker desktop?

Comment: No, you should not. I added an image to the answer.  Could you run  egrep -c '(svm|vmx)' /proc/cpuinfo  ? to verify qty fo proc . You need more than 2

Comment: In your log, I found:
[FAIL] DD0016: is the LinuxKit VM running? vm is not running: failed to open kmsg.log: open <HOME>/.docker/desktop/log/vm/kmsg.log: no such file or directory
[FAIL] DD0017: can a VM be started? vm has not started: failed to open kmsg.log: open <HOME>/.docker/desktop/log/vm/kmsg.log: no such file or directory
[FAIL] DD0003: is the Docker CLI working? exit status 1
[FAIL] DD0014: are the backend processes running? 5 errors occurred:
 * querying com.docker.backend process: is it running as a different user?: readlink /proc/11941/exe: permission denied

Comment: And... * querying com.docker.backend process: is it running as a different user?: readlink /proc/11958/exe: permission denied
 * vpnkit-bridge is not running
 * com.docker.driver.amd64-linux is not running
 * qemu-system-x86_64 is not running

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244854/discussion-between-cyrus-and-mate).

Comment: Hi, @Mate I'm getting the same issue, I'm running Ubuntu 20 in my VirtualBox. I did Install docker-desktop using https://docs.docker.com/desktop/linux/install/ubuntu/. I saw your answer, when I `lsmod | grep kvm`, I get `kvm    864256    0`, When I `multipass launch` I get `launch failed: KVM support is not enabled on this machine. Please ensure the following:
1. The system's CPU supports virtualization.
2. Virtualization is enabled in the system BIOS.
3. The KVM kernel modules are loaded.`

Please help me out If you know anything.

Comment: @PartabSaifuddinZakir  Which software are you use for virtualization?

Comment: @Mate, I was frustrated cuz of the "Docker Stopped" issue so I decided to use Ubuntu 20 as my main OS, currently, I am installing fresh Ubuntu 20, and will try again to install `docker-desktop`. Is there any good blog you know for installing `docker-desktop` please mention it. I'll tell you once I finished installing it.

Comment: Take it easy!  I followed the official: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/linux/install/ubuntu/ .

Comment: Hi @Mate after installing fresh Ubuntu 20, `docker-desktop` runs perfectly, thanks for your kind response.

Comment: @Mate you seem good with docker, I have an issue, If possible please take a look. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72376141/dockermagento-failed-to-add-the-host-to-the-list-of-known-hosts

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem over `Ubuntu` 22.04 VM with `Windows` 11 as main host and `Docker Desktop` 4.9.0

If you are using `Virtualbox` you need to enable nested virtualization support which is available on Windows on versions > 6.0. Also it's important to mention that you need to have disable the Hyper-V, Virtual Machine Platform and the Windows Hypervisor Platform otherwise it won't work.

In order to enable the Nested VT-X/AMD-V in VirtualBox and Windows you need to step by step guide on:

- [How to Enable Nested VT-X/AMD-V in Virtualbox [Step by Step]](https://www.cyberithub.com/how-to-enable-nested-vt-x-amd-v-in-virtualbox-step-by-step/)

1. You need to open Windows Command line terminal by typing CMD on the bottom Search area. Once it shows up, right click on it and select Run as Administrator. This will open the command line terminal in the administrator mode.
2. Now, you need to go to VirtualBox folder using `cd "Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox"` command. This folder contains all the VirtualBox executables components along with other important files in which we need to use VBoxManage.
3. To enable the Nested VT-x/AMD-v in VirtualBox, you need to run `VBoxManage modifyvm <vm_name> --nested-hw-virt on` syntax. EX. I am enabling it for my VM called 'Ubuntu 22.04' so I will use `VBoxManage modifyvm "Ubuntu 22.04" --nested-hw-virt on` command.

You should test that KVM can be used so you can run the command `kvm-ok` on Ubuntu shell [image: kvmok]

In order to install KVM, you need to do the following:

1. Install KVM on Ubuntu 22.04

Next, run the command below to install KVM and additional virtualization packages on Ubuntu 22.04.

```
$ sudo apt install -y qemu-kvm virt-manager libvirt-daemon-system virtinst libvirt-clients bridge-utils
```

Let us break down the packages that we are installing:

- qemu-kvm: An opensource emulator and virtualization package that
  provides hardware emulation.
- virt-manager: A Qt-based graphical interface for managing virtual machines via the libvirt daemon.
- libvirt-daemon-system: A package that provides configuration files
  required to run the libvirt daemon.
- virtinst: A  set of command-line utilities for provisioning and modifying virtual machines.
- libvirt-clients: A set of client-side libraries and APIs for managing and controlling virtual machines & hypervisors from the command line.
- bridge-utils: A set of tools for creating and managing bridge devices.

2. Authorize Users

Only members of kvm user groups can run virtual machines. Add a user to the kvm group by typing:

```
$ sudo adduser ‘<username>’ kvm
```

Then you need to stop and disable docker

```
$ sudo service docker stop
$ sudo systemctl disable docker.service
$ sudo systemctl disable docker.socket
```

Afterwards, you reboot and Docker Desktop is going to be setup

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 22.0. Thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

Docker needs virtualization for work. So, you can turn it on in BIOS. That worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: In my case, this video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jb9gPJPd5QY, was helpful. It was in the overclocking section of my BIOS. I guess this may vary from BIOS to BIOS. You might have to dig.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

Open `%AppData%\Docker\settings.json` and set

- `useWindowsContainers`: `true`
- `wslEngineEnabled`: `true`

Comment: useWindowsContainers??? 

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was getting the error **"Docker Desktop stopped"**.

Then tried re-installed many times, but now getting the error **"running VM: running VM and dependencies: running VM: running qemu: qemu: waiting for qemu process: exit status 1"**,

Finally, I noticed the virtualization was disabled in my **BIOS**, the option was called **"SMV mode"**, but it might be different on your machine.

Now, Docker is working again.

Credits:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76655270/3779757