# Docker+Magento: Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts

Tags: php, git, docker, magento, command-line-interface

I'm trying to clone out the Magento 2 repo from github. I'm checking out the code with git from within the docker container since I'm using `bin/cli` .I've added an SSH key into my system also in the Github account, but I'm still getting this error (Please see image). When I enter the command `bin/cli git clone git@github.com:magento/magento2.git` it gives me an error. Please help me out if you know this issue.

[image]

**`docker-compose.yml`**

```
## Mark Shust's Docker Configuration for Magento
## (https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento)
##
## Version 42.0.0

## To use SSH, see https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento#ssh
## Linux users, see https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento#linux

## If you changed the default Docker network, you may need to replace
## 172.17.0.1 in this file with the result of:
## docker network inspect bridge --format='{{(index .IPAM.Config 0).Gateway}}'

version: "3"

services:
  app:
    image: markoshust/magento-nginx:1.18-7
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
      - "443:8443"
    volumes: &appvolumes
      - ~/.composer:/var/www/.composer:cached
      - ~/.ssh/id_rsa:/var/www/.ssh/id_rsa:cached
      - ~/.ssh/known_hosts:/var/www/.ssh/known_hosts:cached
      - appdata:/var/www/html
      - sockdata:/sock
      - ssldata:/etc/nginx/certs
    extra_hosts: &appextrahosts
      ## M1 Mac support to fix Docker delay, see #566
      - "app:172.17.0.1"
      - "phpfpm:172.17.0.1"
      - "db:172.17.0.1"
      - "redis:172.17.0.1"
      - "elasticsearch:172.17.0.1"
      - "rabbitmq:172.17.0.1"
      ## Selenium support, replace "magento.test" with URL of your site
      - "magento.test:172.17.0.1"

  phpfpm:
    image: markoshust/magento-php:8.1-fpm-0
    volumes: *appvolumes
    extra_hosts: *appextrahosts
    env_file: env/phpfpm.env

  db:
    image: mariadb:10.4
    command: --max_allowed_packet=64M
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    env_file: env/db.env
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    extra_hosts: *appextrahosts

  redis:
    image: redis:6.2-alpine
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    extra_hosts: *appextrahosts

  elasticsearch:
    image: markoshust/magento-elasticsearch:7.16-0
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    environment:
      - "discovery.type=single-node"
      ## Set custom heap size to avoid memory errors
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1g -Xmx1g"
      ## Avoid test failures due to small disks
      ## More info at https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento/issues/488
      - "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled=false"
      - "index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete"
    extra_hosts: *appextrahosts

  rabbitmq:
    image: markoshust/magento-rabbitmq:3.9-0
    ports:
      - "15672:15672"
      - "5672:5672"
    volumes:
      - rabbitmqdata:/var/lib/rabbitmq
    env_file: env/rabbitmq.env
    extra_hosts: *appextrahosts

  mailcatcher:
    image: sj26/mailcatcher
    ports:
      - "1080:1080"
    extra_hosts: *appextrahosts

  ## Blackfire support, uncomment to enable
  #blackfire:
  #  image: blackfire/blackfire:2
  #  ports:
  #    - "8307"
  #  env_file: env/blackfire.env

  ## Selenium support, uncomment to enable
  #selenium:
  #  image: selenium/standalone-chrome-debug:3.8.1
  #  ports:
  #    - "5900:5900"
  #  extra_hosts: *appextrahosts

volumes:
  appdata:
  dbdata:
  rabbitmqdata:
  sockdata:
  ssldata:
```

`Docker Images`

[image]

`Docker Project Root Dir`

[image]
Thanks.

Comment: Where is located your SSH private key? Under `/var/www/.ssh/` ?

Comment: @MartinTovmassian `/home/partab/.ssh` is this a path issue ?

Comment: looks like so since it check for a key with under the path `/var/www/.ssh/id_rsa`

Comment: where should I set the path, under `docker-composer.yml` ?

Comment: What Docker image do you use?

Comment: I've also added `bin/bash` dir (See image)

Comment: Please update your question with your `docker-compose.yml` file too. It will be easier to reproduce the case on my side.

Comment: @MartinTovmassian question updated with more detail & `docker-compose.yml`

Comment: I think it's the permission issue as you can see in docker container `/var/www/.ssh` as root permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the issue with a fresh install as explained in the [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/r/markoshust/magento-nginx/).

And as the error message says `Load key "/var/www/.ssh/id_rsa": Is a directory` problem is that the volume used to mount the SSH key in the container is not correctly set. Here `id_rsa` is mounted as a directory whereas it is a file.

In the `docker-compose.yml` under the volume section of the service **app** change the line

```
- ~/.ssh/id_rsa:/var/www/.ssh/id_rsa:cached
```

to

```
- ~/.ssh:/var/www/.ssh:cached
```

Comment: I'm on it. Creating a new container, also replaced line as you mention, will let you know.