# Docker Desktop says "Docker Desktop stopped..." in Ubuntu 22

Tags: docker, docker-desktop, ubuntu-22.04

When I open up Docker Desktop, I get a "Docker Desktop stopped...". And when I open the Troubleshoot page, the "Restart" button is greyed out.

I've tried multiple things:

- Checked Virtualization is enabled - it is
- Tried the steps described here: [Docker is running. Docker Desktop says "Docker Desktop stopped..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72281976/docker-is-running-docker-desktop-says-docker-desktop-stopped)
- Checked that I was running the right desktop - Gnome.

Running `service docker status`

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset>
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2022-07-26 21:48:21 MDT; 2min 0s ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
   Main PID: 4957 (dockerd)
      Tasks: 27
     Memory: 108.5M
        CPU: 374ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
             └─4957 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/cont>
```

When I run the built-in diagnostic tool, using the command
`sudo /opt/docker-desktop/bin/com.docker.diagnose check`,
I get the following output:

```
Please investigate the following 3 issues:

1 : The test: can a VM be started?
    Failed with: vm has not started: failed to open kmsg.log: open /root/.docker/desktop/log/vm/kmsg.log: no such file or directory

The Docker engine runs inside a Linux VM. Therefore we must be able to start Virtual Machines.

2 : The test: is the application running?
    Failed with: Docker is not running

Is the Docker Desktop application running?

3 : The test: is Context set to a Docker Desktop context?
    Failed with: CLI context is set to docker-ce engine

If the Docker Context is set to 'default', docker CLI is not addressing Docker Desktop engine.
```

#2 seems to still happen, even though I try to restart docker, and running `sudo systemctl status docker` shows that docker is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using fedora 37 , and after struggling for a day I found in my BIOS virtualization is disabled.
enabling virtualization in BIOS helped me getting rid of the error