# Running docker on a virtual machine with Ubuntu, when I open docker it says "Docker has stopped" and the icon flashes?

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu

When I searched Google for why this might happen on a VM I found this Stackoverflow post: [Docker is running. Docker Desktop says "Docker Desktop stopped..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72281976/docker-is-running-docker-desktop-says-docker-desktop-stopped)

and so I followed the steps in this link: https://www.cyberithub.com/how-to-enable-nested-vt-x-amd-v-in-virtualbox-step-by-step/

After I did all that I re-opened my VM and now when I go to start Docker it shows the Docker icon loading, the window pops up and immediately closes.

How can I troubleshoot this issue further to resolve?

Thanks

Googled and found stackoverflow post: [Docker is running. Docker Desktop says "Docker Desktop stopped..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72281976/docker-is-running-docker-desktop-says-docker-desktop-stopped)

And found this website to enable nested visualization: https://www.cyberithub.com/how-to-enable-nested-vt-x-amd-v-in-virtualbox-step-by-step/

Followed this link to install Docker on linux: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/ubuntu/

Comment: Most of this question is links to other material.  What code did you personally write, and what results is it giving?  Please [edit] the question to include a [mcve].

Comment: @DavidMaze This is more of a troubleshooting question maybe I should have asked it instead on superuser but figured more ppl would have experience with docker here. I've followed those links and am stuck.