# Unable to launch Docker Desktop on ubuntu

Tags: docker

When i launch docker desktop through application manager in ubuntu the error shows :**running VM: running VM and dependencies: running VM: running qemu: qemu: waiting for qemu process: exit status 1**
I do not know where exactly is the problem. Is it some installation issue ?

Comment: use the `journalctl` command to view the system logs and look for any Docker-related errors or warnings!

Comment: check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72281976/docker-is-running-docker-desktop-says-docker-desktop-stopped/72282039#72282039

Comment: (Do you _actually_ need Docker Desktop?  On a native-Linux host you should be able to install the Docker engine only, which will have fewer dependencies but also won't include the GUI tooling.)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, and to resolve it, I tried enabling [KVM virtualization support](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/linux-install/#kvm-virtualization-support). However, I received the following error:

modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'kvm_amd': Operation not supported

I managed to fix it by enabling virtualization support in the BIOS. In my BIOS, the option was called "SMV mode," but it might be different on your machine.

Comment: Thank you a lot, in my case it's also called "SMV mode" and it was disabled in the BIOS